# Universal wiki Converter throws Out Of Memory Error

Tags: bash, confluence

I am trying to use uwc 4.0 to convert a moinmoin site, but running out of heap space, no matter how much memory i increase. Currently its (run_cmdline.sh)

```
# BEGIN
#!/bin/bash

MYCWD=`pwd`

CLASSPATHORIG=$CLASSPATH

CLASSPATH="uwc.jar"
for file in lib/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$MYCWD/$file:$CLASSPATH
done

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CLASSPATHORIG

export CLASSPATH

# run out of the sample_files dir
#cd sample_files
java -Xdebug -Xms2G -Xmx4G $APPLE_ARGS -classpath $CLASSPATH com.atlassian.uwc.ui.UWCCommandLineInterface $1 $2 $3 $4
## END
```

i run the following on command line:

```
sudo ./run_cmdline.sh conf/confluenceSettings.properties conf/converter.moinmoin.properties /opt/atlassian/moin/
```

P.S. If i use just ONE Small folder from the moinmoin pages directory, and try to export it, i get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:542)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.ConverterEngine.createPageTable(ConverterEngine.java:2112)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.ConverterEngine.sendPage(ConverterEngine.java:2014)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.ConverterEngine.sendPage(ConverterEngine.java:1719)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.ConverterEngine.writePages(ConverterEngine.java:1356)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.ConverterEngine.convert(ConverterEngine.java:421)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.ConverterEngine.convert(ConverterEngine.java:215)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.UWCCommandLineInterface.convert(UWCCommandLineInterface.java:175)
    at com.atlassian.uwc.ui.UWCCommandLineInterface.main(UWCCommandLineInterface.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Confluence 3.5 and lower versions are supported by UWC , and not any Confluence version above 3.5